# Form post to db only once, php

Tags: php, database, forms, post

a form is posted to db only once, i have to delete the row in db for the form to post new form data again. I tried several modifications from internet but didnt allowed me to post after the first successful time

Form:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<h5>A form:</h5>
<input class="right-inputs" id="field1" type="number" name="field1" placeholder="Enter stuff">
<input class="right-inputs" id="field2" type="text" name="field2" value="" readonly>
<script src="js/insert.js"></script>
<button class="btn-cmn" type="submit" name="submit">post</button>
</form>
```

post.php:

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

$var1 = $_POST['field1'];
$var2 = $_POST['field2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `a_table` (column1, column2) VALUES ('$var1', '$var2')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_close($conn);

header("Location: page.php?post=success");

?>
```

db.php:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "database_sample";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

?>
```

**your table structure look like :**

[image]

Comment: Please mention your question and answer clear, What's the issue.

Comment: it only posts to the database once, if you submit a second time it doesnt add the data to the database, i have to delete the previous data for it to submit the new inputs, the question is, how do I make it work without having to delete the first posted data in the database?

Comment: You have to create in table the field like primay key i.e. auto increment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have Primary Key in your table that not automatic generate value. So you can't add more row while have same Primary key..
Make sure you generate unique key for primary or have auto increment number for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think issues in your database to put error_reporting(E_ALL); in your php page in top section then after try to insert so get some error view in your code.